# Google maps - search address / cities from mysql database

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was a amazed finding a somewhat easy to use example for a Google maps setup which would allow you to search for certain cities in your DB. The article can be found here:

http://code.google.com/intl/da-DK/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html

After using some time to getting it work and looking around for some addons, I noticed the article was old and apart of the now deprecated v2 API. The current API is v3.

I'm wondering if there is a similar tutorial out there for the new v. 3 API?
So frustrating having found exactly what I need and finding out its based on something deprecated.

You can see a live example here: (try and search for "mountain view"):
http://sgsdev.com/previews/gMaps/

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html

Comment: Thanks - but what im rly looking for is a tutorial setup like the link provided above

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that there is a tutorial online for this at this time.

You might try to port it to v3 yourself and post questions to StackOverflow with any problems you encounter.

Migrating the v2 Maps stuff in that sample code to v3 should be pretty straightforward.  The hard part might be to figure out what to do with the GDownloadUrl and GXml stuff.  Some things to consider there might be:

- Change the PHP to serve JSON rather than XML for easier use here?
- Use jQuery ajax() to simplify things?  But jQuery often doesn't play well with Google Maps, I've heard.
- Maybe use microAjax.js to fill in for GDownloadUrl?